# Pythonic way of converting integers to string

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> foo = 1
>>> type(foo)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(str(foo))
<type 'str'>
>>> type(`foo`)
<type 'str'>
```

Which is the more Pythonic way of converting integers to strings? I have always been using the first method but I now find the second method more readable. Is there a practical difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[String conversions using backticks](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#string-conversions) are a shorthand notation for calling [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) on a value. For integers, the resulting output of `str()` and `repr()` *happens* to be the same, but it is *not* the same operation:

```
>>> example = 'bar'
>>> str(example)
'bar'
>>> repr(example)
"'bar'"
>>> `example`
"'bar'"
```

The backticks syntax was [removed from Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax); I wouldn't use it, as an explicit `str()` or `repr()` call is far clearer in its intent.

Note that you have more options to convert integers to strings; you can use [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or [old style string formatting operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) to interpolate an integer into a larger string:

```
>>> print 'Hello world! The answer is, as always, {}'.format(42)
Hello world! The answer is, as always, 42
```

which is much more powerful than using string concatenation.

Comment: Cheers for the "shorthand notation for calling repr()" bit. Learn something new everyday.